# c++ code for udp server handling multiple clients simultaneously

Tags: c++, unix

I have to make a DNS server in which I have to use UDP and to handle multiple clients queries simultaneously.How would i generate response to an appropriate client if multiple clients are querying at the same time? And also if 2 or more clients queried for same ip address then how would i differentiate between them and generate respone appropriately?

Comment: Learning what the arguments to [`recvfrom`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/recvfrom.html) does might be a good help.

Comment: In general, the classic 'Unix Network Programming' book (by Stevens, there is now an updated edition by another author since he died many years ago) is still the nr 1 reference for TCP and UDP programming. There is also example code that you can download, just google it.